# Are there any experiments showing any deviation from the conventional formula for the Lorentz force?

Tags: electromagnetism, forces

I want to know if there are experiments showing that the second term of the Lorentz force formula is measured slightly differently from the conventional $qv×B$ for some fundamental particles.

Comment: Do you have reason to believe it should deviate for different elementary particles? Or perhaps some curiosity if there is some form of violation of the law?

Comment: @Triatticus My article regarding the origin of the Lorentz force is about to be accepted in a peer-reviewed journal. The reviewer indeed asked me this question as if s/he was too ignorant of the answer!

Comment: I would very much recommend this old Lecture by J. D. Jackson: http://cds.cern.ch/record/118393

Comment: The bulk of the fits of the data of elementary particles in the standard model of particle physics are fited with the Lorentz transformations being axiomatic in the models. Since any deviations of data from the fits involve esoteric parts of the model, not the axiomatic lorentz transformations this could be the data you need? example https://theconversation.com/the-standard-model-of-particle-physics-may-be-broken-an-expert-explains-182081